# Crystal Reports 2011 viewer scrolling issue

Tags: crystal-reports

Background:
Crystal reports 2008 prior. Now upgraded to crystal reports 2011

We have crystal reports version 14.0.2.364 installed to delivery reports to clients.

This problem appeared after the upgrade where someone gets a report delivered and the browser\crystal report viewer attempts to "auto-scroll" to a page automatically for you. Then some kind of issue causes it to scroll back to the previous page.

It continues to do this in a infinte loop where the browser\viewer never holds still long enough to do anything with the report.

Does anyone know how this has happened? (Again we have service pack 1 and 2 for the crystal reports 2011 package but I can find NOTHING on this problem anywhere).

Anyone else familiar with this problem or have seen this issue? (Happens in IE and Chrome btw)

UPDATE: It appears this problem is related purely to view size. If the view is set to 100 percent and with that view you can see the 2nd page, it starts to auto process the next page to display. So I tried a report that worked, and changed to view to 75% and the problem started up because that brought the 2nd page into view on the browser. This cannot possibly be how this is going to have to work (purely based on whether or not the second page is viewable based on local settings determines whether or not the browser\viewer goes into an infinite loop back and forth)

FINAL UPDATE (Resolution) : A setting in a web.xml file in the reporting services folder that instructs crystal report viewer to pre-render ALL pages of a report before viewing was the solution. Before this it was rendering ONLY the page the user was trying to view, hence if you have 2 pages in view it would infinitely loop in an attempt to display both pages. This setting was unfortunately buried in folders that are related to websphere which powers the application that runs our reports. It was called crystal_use_asynchronous_requests and we had to set it to true. Restarted websphere, and this resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

FINAL UPDATE (Resolution) : A setting in a web.xml file in the reporting services folder that instructs crystal report viewer to pre-render ALL pages of a report before viewing was the solution. Before this it was rendering ONLY the page the user was trying to view, hence if you have 2 pages in view it would infinitely loop in an attempt to display both pages. This setting was unfortunately buried in folders that are related to websphere which powers the application that runs our reports. It was called crystal_use_asynchronous_requests and we had to set it to true. Restarted websphere, and this resolved the issue